# react native navigation screen won't ReRender

Tags: react-native

when go from category to productList for the first time everything is right but after i came back and try to go for second time list screen won't rerender or refresh what ever you call. is there anyone has suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list Screen gets data on mount and that's it. If you want it to gets a new data every time the category name changes you have to add it to the useEffect dependencies like so.

```
  const categoryName = navigation.route.params.categoryName;
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  },[categoryName]);
```

Now every time categoryName changes getData gets called.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tabs just add `unmountOnBlur: true,` in the <Tab.Screen/> of the screen you are in

Comment: actually another person did the all these navigation and screens, i'm just trying to bind with api. he used drawer screen